# how do i get the html and style of this view?

Tags: html, css, web

i'm a beginner in web programming, and i need to create a web site for a school project.

In my website i want to have this view:

[image: the view i need]

that i saw on a [website](http://francois-deleglise.fr/2012/11/associer-une-photo-a-un-resultat-de-recherche-google/).

how do i get the html of that?

Comment: write some code? ;-)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire

Answer (score 0):

Use your browser's tools!

First, as you mentioned "views" – "views" don't exist in HTML. But there are tags. Common tags are `<a href="...">...</a>`, `<strong>bold text</strong>`, `<div>...</div>`, ... What you want is to grab a tag with several child tags.

In Firefox, there's a tool called [Page inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector). It'll let you inspect the site's source code interactively (e.g. you hover over a tag and it'll be highlighted). With that, you can easily find the needed HTML tags. But you also need the CSS styles for each tag. If you click on a tag, the CSS styles are shown on the right. You have to copy them to your stylesheet and maybe you'll have to modify them to match your different HTML structure.

There's something similar in Chrome, too.

But please note that it's not very nice to simply copy-paste this code without modifying it. It's a good idea to discover how you can do something like this, but I strongly recommend to change it, to have something own!